# How can I support PUT method in my Spring Boot app?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm using Angular CLI and Spring Boot.

Everything works (getEmployee, deleteEmployee) but when I want to Update or Create (same method, and same HTML Form) an Employee I get in HTML Console/Network this error:

```
[ERROR] message: "Request method 'PUT' not supported"
```

This is my Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class EmployeeController {

    private final EmployeeServiceImpl employeeService;

    @Autowired
    public EmployeeController(EmployeeServiceImpl employeeService) {
        this.employeeService = employeeService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/employees")
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        return employeeService.findAllEmployees();
    }

    @GetMapping("/employees/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> getEmployeeById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long employeeId) {
        Employee employee = employeeService.findById(employeeId).get();
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(employee);
    }


    @PutMapping("/employees/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> updateEmployee(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long employeeId,
                                                   @Valid @RequestBody Employee employeeDetails) {
        Employee employee = employeeService.findById(employeeId).get();

        employee.setEmailAddress(employeeDetails.getEmailAddress());
        employee.setLastName(employeeDetails.getLastName());
        employee.setFirstName(employeeDetails.getFirstName());
        employee.setStatus(employeeDetails.getStatus());
        employee.setSkills(employeeDetails.getSkills());
        final Employee updatedEmployee = employeeService.saveEmployee(employee);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(updatedEmployee);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/employees/{id}")
    public Map<String, Boolean> deleteEmployee(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long employeeId) {
        Employee employee = employeeService.findById(employeeId).get();

        employeeService.deleteEmployee(employee);
        Map<String, Boolean> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("deleted", Boolean.TRUE);
        return response;
    }
}//close class
```

This is also my CORSConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class CORSConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "DELETE","PUT");
    }
}//close class
```

Here you can see my Angular code:

EmployeeDetail.ts

```
export class EmployeeDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  employee: Employee;
  skills;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute, /* holds information about the route to this instance of the EmployeeDetailsComponent */
    private location: Location,
    private employeeService: EmployeeService,
    private skillService: SkillService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getEmployee();
    this.skillService.getSkills().subscribe(res => this.skills = res);
  }

  getEmployee(): void {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    if (id === -1) {
      this.employee = new Employee();
    } else {
      this.employeeService.getEmployee(id)
        .subscribe(employee => this.employee = employee);
    }
  }

  save(): void {
    this.employeeService.updateEmployee(this.employee)
      .subscribe(() => this.goBack());
    console.log('test', this.employee);
  }

  goBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }
}
```

When I click on save the method redirect me to the Update method in my service;

service.ts

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeeService {

  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/employees';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


  /** GET Employees from the server */
  getEmployees(): Observable<Employee[]> {
    return this.http.get<Employee[]>(this.baseUrl);
  }

  getEmployee(id: number): Observable<Employee> {
    const url = this.baseUrl + '/' + id;
    return this.http.get<Employee>(url);
  }

  /** PUT: update the employee on the server */
  updateEmployee(employee: Employee): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(this.baseUrl, employee, httpOptions);
  }

  deleteEmployee(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`, { responseType: 'text' });
  }
}
```

This is my first SpringBoot app, also w/Angular so I never seen this error before.

What can I do?

Comment: update your addCorsMappings method with .allowedMethods(" * ")
.allowedOrigins(" * ")

Comment: like this?

      public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowedMethods(" * ") .allowedOrigins(" * ");

Comment: can u post your angular code on how you make the put request ?

Comment: `@Configuration
public class CORSConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedHeaders("*").allowedMethods("*")
.allowedOrigins("*");
                
    }
}`

Comment: @GovindParashar I did it, but nothing change.

Comment: run your application debug mode I think error something different

Comment: @SantoshBalaji I edited my question w/ angular code.

Comment: add this entry in your application.properties logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG

Comment: @GovindParashar I did it and get this

     [ERROR]  2019-03-13 14:35:43.463 DEBUG 11260 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Wed Mar 13 14:35:43 CET 2019, status=405, error=Method Not Allowed, message=Request metho (truncated)...]
2019-03-13 14:35:43.466 DEBUG 11260 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 405

Comment: Your angular code seems to be sending the request to /api/employees, but the mapping in the spring code is /api/employees/{id}.

Answer (score 1):

Your Angular code shows the following method

```
  updateEmployee(employee: Employee): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(this.baseUrl, employee, httpOptions);
  }
```

You did not include id in angular side. But for your spring boot side requires  id. Since you are not passing the id the framework cannot find matching method resulting in 405 method not allowed error

```
@PutMapping("/employees/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Employee> updateEmployee(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long employeeId,
                                               @Valid @RequestBody Employee employeeDetails) {
    Employee employee = employeeService.findById(employeeId).get();

    employee.setEmailAddress(employeeDetails.getEmailAddress());
    employee.setLastName(employeeDetails.getLastName());
    employee.setFirstName(employeeDetails.getFirstName());
    employee.setStatus(employeeDetails.getStatus());
    employee.setSkills(employeeDetails.getSkills());
    final Employee updatedEmployee = employeeService.saveEmployee(employee);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(updatedEmployee);
}
```

Comment: You can do it the same way as delete method or try to add id details inside the employee object

Comment: Ok I edited like this:

  updateEmployee(employee: Employee): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(`${this.baseUrl}/${employee.id}`, employee, httpOptions);
  }

If I Edit or Create i get this error:

error: "Internal Server Error"
message: "No value present"
path: "/api/employees/4"
status: 500

Comment: **UPDATE** 
Edit works well, create get error 500 like the comment before.

Comment: what is the purpose of create method ?

Comment: the create method is the same of update, I understand the error, the id is autoIncrement so I need to be able to pass the new id, that's why It can find the new User. But I don't know why when I create a new User it doesn't generate the id. Any ideas? (I didn't set it in the controller)

Comment: Employee employee = employeeService.findById(employeeId).get();  The output of this line will be null since employee with the id is not present. Create new employee object if employee is null

Comment: @s2theergio if this answer worked for you, accept it. Don't edit the question.